# Vb.net Error "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: vb.net, file-upload

I've this code to save a file:

```
[...]
Dim strNomeFile As String
        strNomeFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFile)
        Dim strPercorsoFileUpload As String
        strPercorsoFileUpload = "d:\web\TecBuild\cartellaUpload"
        Dim milliseconds = CLng(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds)
        Try
            mioFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(strPercorsoFileUpload & "\" & milliseconds & "_" & strNomeFile)
[...]
```

I'm trying to upload these file: "TestJanuary" (without extension and double quotes), but, with Internet Explorer 11 I receive the error: "The given path's format is not supported". But, this is only a problem of an user's PC, my PC is uploading the same file well.

The PCs are both with IE 11 in compatibility mode. Same Windows 7. Different domain user.
Upload is from this folder: C:\Users\surname.name\Desktop\

Any suggestion?

Thanks